# Regex - Match year and string replace and substitute everything else

Tags: regex

Hoping y'all can help me with some regex.

*An few example strings*:

- 1990 Ford Explorer
- 1994 Ford Explorer Eddie Bauer
- 1996 Jeep Cherokee Sport
- 2000 Aston Martin DB7

I am looking to get the "model / trim" so I'd like to match the year / make and remove it from the string.

*In the examples given, I'd want to end up with*:

- Explorer
- Explorer Eddie Bauer
- Cherokee Sport
- DB7

Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: What if the make consists of more than one word like the fourth example? There's no way to separate the model from the make in this case unless you have a list of all the makes to check against. What programming language are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Javascript - right now I am getting the year by `(\d+)(.*)` and model by something like `.*(Ford|Jeep|Aston Martin).*`. Not really sure how to put it all together and both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
^\d{4}\s(Alfa Romeo|Aston Martin|Audi|Bentley|Benz|BMW|Bugatti|Cadillac|Chevrolet|Chrysler|Citroen|Corvette|DAF|Dacia|Daewoo|Daihatsu|Datsun|De Lorean|Dino|Dodge|Farboud|Ferrari|Fiat|Ford|Honda|Hummer|Hyundai|Jaguar|Jeep|KIA|Koenigsegg|Lada|Lamborghini|Lancia|Land Rover|Lexus|Ligier|Lincoln|Lotus|Martini|Maserati|Maybach|Mazda|McLaren|Mercedes|Mercedes-Benz|Mini|Mitsubishi|Nissan|Noble|Opel|Peugeot|Pontiac|Porsche|Renault|Rolls-Royce|Rover|Saab|Seat|Skoda|Smart|Spyker|Subaru|Suzuki|Toyota|Vauxhall|Volkswagen|Volvo)\s
```

Replace with empty string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wpfwxL/1)

Car Brands [Reference](https://www.searchify.ca/keyword-list-car-brands/)